# Django - Detecting Value of Field in Model - Views

Tags: django, templates, view

I need to loop through all field objects of a model in Django. Once I look through I need to detect if in any of the entries of data this specific field(type) is equal to "Date1". If it is I need it to send a variable(val) that is a string equal to "True" to the Django templates. I have everything set and it seems simple and it seems like it should work. On its own, the val can send a value to the template when it is not in an if statement and the for loop also properly works. **Even when "Date1" exists as a value in the type field of an entry in the model "Field_Repo1" the val isn't sent and the if statement is never iterated through(I know this by using prints)**. **No matter what the if statement is never run through**. Code Below. Thanks in advance.

```
context = {}
context['Field_Repo1'] = Field_Repo1.objects.filter(user=response.user)
for type1 in Field_Repo1.objects.values_list('type'):
    if type1 == "Date1":
        val = "True"
        context['val'] = val
        print(val)
        print(AHHHHHHHHHHHH)

if response.method == 'POST':
    form = Field_Repo1_Form(response.POST, response.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = response.user
        instance.save()
        response.user.Field_Repo1.add(instance)
        return redirect('repo1')
else:
    form = Field_Repo1_Form()
context['form'] = form

return render(response, 'sheets/add_fields/repo1_add_field.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `values_list()` function returns a queryset of tuples. The statement in your `for` loop `if type1 == "Date1":` is trying to compare equality between `"Date1"` and a tuple, which will never be true. The tuples in the query set all are of length 1 since you only passed a single field to the `values_list()` function, so you should be able to do `if type1[0] == "Date1":` for your comparison.